# Unit testing Node.js and WebSockets (Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, websocket, socket.io

Could anyone provide a rock-solid, dead-simple unit test for Node.js using WebSockets (Socket.io)?

I'm using socket.io for Node.js, and have looked at socket.io-client for establishing the client connection to a server in the test.  However, I seem to be missing something.

In the example below, "worked..." never gets printed out.

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
, assert = require('assert')
, expect = require('expect.js');

describe('Suite of unit tests', function() {

    describe('First (hopefully useful) test', function() {

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
        socket.on('connect', function(done) {
            console.log('worked...');
            done();
        });

        it('Doing some things with indexOf()', function() {
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(5)).to.be.equal(-1);
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(0)).to.be.equal(-1);
        });

    });
});
```

Instead, I simply get:

```
  Suite of unit tests
    First (hopefully useful) test
      ✓ Doing some things with indexOf() 


  1 test complete (26 ms)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this mocha or jasmine tests? For asynchronous mocha tests (which this is) your test function needs to take a callback `function(testDone)` so mocha knows to treat it appropriately. This may actually be working but mocha is exiting before the 'connect' event fires because mocha doesn't know it should wait.

Comment: [Socket.io's docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/testing/) have examples for mocha, jest, and tape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dealing with callbacks and promises yourself can be difficult and non trivial examples quickly become very complex and hard to read.

There is a tool called [socket.io-await-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-await-test) available via NPM that allows you to suspend/wait in a test until events have been triggered using the await keyword.

```
  describe("wait for tests", () => {
    it("resolves when a number of events are received", async () => {
        const tester = new SocketTester(client);
        const pongs = tester.on('pong');
        
        client.emit('ping', 1);
        client.emit('ping', 2);
        await pongs.waitForEvents(2) // Blocks until the server emits "pong" twice. 

        assert.equal(pongs.get(0), 2)
        assert.equal(pongs.get(1), 3)
    })
})
```

Comment: How has this got 0 votes? Most elegant solution I've seen. Have my vote

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for

Comment: OP here... since the original post, all the unit testing has seen a pile of improvements. happy to elevate/highlight posts like these that answer the question in a better/modern fashion. gonna 1+ this myself :)

Answer (score 73):

After further poking and prodding, I found some [incredibly useful information](http://blog.foundry376.com/2012/09/connecting-to-a-socket-io-server-from-node-js-unit-tests). In the author's example, he points out the critical step of establishing socket listeners in the **`before`** hooks.

This example works:

> Assuming a server is listening for socket connections at `localhost:3001`, of course

```js
var io = require('socket.io-client')
, assert = require('assert')
, expect = require('expect.js');

describe('Suite of unit tests', function() {

    var socket;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        // Setup
        socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001', {
            'reconnection delay' : 0
            , 'reopen delay' : 0
            , 'force new connection' : true
        });
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('worked...');
            done();
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('disconnected...');
        })
    });

    afterEach(function(done) {
        // Cleanup
        if(socket.connected) {
            console.log('disconnecting...');
            socket.disconnect();
        } else {
            // There will not be a connection unless you have done() in beforeEach, socket.on('connect'...)
            console.log('no connection to break...');
        }
        done();
    });

    describe('First (hopefully useful) test', function() {

        it('Doing some things with indexOf()', function(done) {
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(5)).to.be.equal(-1);
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(0)).to.be.equal(-1);
            done();
        });

        it('Doing something else with indexOf()', function(done) {
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(5)).to.be.equal(-1);
            expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(0)).to.be.equal(-1);
            done();
        });

    });

});
```

I found that the placement of `done()` in the `beforeEach`, `socket.on('connect'...)` listener was crucial to having the connection get established.  For example, if you comment out `done()` in the listener, then add it one scope out (*just before exiting the `beforeEach`*), you'll see the *"no connection to break..."* message instead of the *"disconnecting..."* message. Like so:

```js
beforeEach(function(done) {
    // Setup
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001', {
        'reconnection delay' : 0
        , 'reopen delay' : 0
        , 'force new connection' : true
    });
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('worked...');
        //done();
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('disconnected...');
    });
    done();
});
```

I'm new to Mocha, so there's probably a very obvious reason to the initiated for placing `done()` within the socket scope itself. Hopefully that little detail will save others in my shoes from hair pulling.

For me, the above test (*with correct scoping of `done()`*) outputs:

```js
  Suite of unit tests
    First (hopefully useful) test
      ◦ Doing some things with indexOf(): worked...
      ✓ Doing some things with indexOf() 
disconnecting...
disconnected...
      ◦ Doing something else with indexOf(): worked...
      ✓ Doing something else with indexOf() 
disconnecting...
disconnected...


  2 tests complete (93 ms)
```

Comment: Add {'forceNew': true} to the options when create a new socket. In this way, you can create multiple client sockets in the unit tests.

Comment: @mysterlune The done() in the scope of socket.on('connect'...) ensures the socket connects before the tests start running. The operation is queued until done() is called within the previous context.

Comment: Would you be able to show a test example of the client emitting something and the server responding?

Answer (score 12):

Offering an extension of the accepted answer here. Has basic client to server communication useful as boilerplate for other future tests. Using mocha, chai, and expect.

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
  , io_server = require('socket.io').listen(3001);

describe('basic socket.io example', function() {

  var socket;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    // Setup
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001', {
      'reconnection delay' : 0
      , 'reopen delay' : 0
      , 'force new connection' : true
      , transports: ['websocket']
    });

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      done();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      // console.log('disconnected...');
    });
  });

  afterEach((done) => {
    // Cleanup
    if(socket.connected) {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
    io_server.close();
    done();
  });

  it('should communicate', (done) => {
    // once connected, emit Hello World
    io_server.emit('echo', 'Hello World');

    socket.once('echo', (message) => {
      // Check that the message matches
      expect(message).to.equal('Hello World');
      done();
    });

    io_server.on('connection', (socket) => {
      expect(socket).to.not.be.null;
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Would you be able to show a test example of the client emitting something and the server responding?

Answer (score 4):

Check out this **boilerplate** solution that's based on **promises** and **good practice**.
You can test your servers entire io events with it, no sweat.
You just need to copy a boilerplate test and add your own code as needed.

Checkout the repo on GitHub for full source code.

https://github.com/PatMan10/testing_socketIO_server

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const ev = require("../utils/events");
const logger = require("../utils/logger");

// initSocket returns a promise
// success: resolve a new socket object
// fail: reject a error
const initSocket = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // create socket for communication
      const socket = io("localhost:5000", {
        "reconnection delay": 0,
        "reopen delay": 0,
        "force new connection": true
      });

      // define event handler for sucessfull connection
      socket.on(ev.CONNECT, () => {
        logger.info("connected");
        resolve(socket);
      });

      // if connection takes longer than 5 seconds throw error
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error("Failed to connect wihtin 5 seconds."));
      }, 5000);
    }
  );
};


// destroySocket returns a promise
// success: resolve true
// fail: resolve false
const destroySocket = socket => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // check if socket connected
    if (socket.connected) {
      // disconnect socket
      logger.info("disconnecting...");
      socket.disconnect();
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      // not connected
      logger.info("no connection to break...");
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
};

describe("test suit: Echo & Bello", () => {
  test("test: ECHO", async () => {
    // create socket for communication
    const socketClient = await initSocket();

    // create new promise for server response
    const serverResponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // define a handler for the test event
      socketClient.on(ev.res_ECHO, data4Client => {
        //process data received from server
        const { message } = data4Client;
        logger.info("Server says: " + message);

        // destroy socket after server responds
        destroySocket(socketClient);

        // return data for testing
        resolve(data4Client);
      });

      // if response takes longer than 5 seconds throw error
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error("Failed to get reponse, connection timed out..."));
      }, 5000);
    });

    // define data 4 server
    const data4Server = { message: "CLIENT ECHO" };

    // emit event with data to server
    logger.info("Emitting ECHO event");
    socketClient.emit(ev.com_ECHO, data4Server);

    // wait for server to respond
    const { status, message } = await serverResponse;

    // check the response data
    expect(status).toBe(200);
    expect(message).toBe("SERVER ECHO");
  });

  test("test BELLO", async () => {
    const socketClient = await initSocket();
    const serverResponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      socketClient.on(ev.res_BELLO, data4Client => {
        const { message } = data4Client;
        logger.info("Server says: " + message);
        destroySocket(socketClient);
        resolve(data4Client);
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(new Error("Failed to get reponse, connection timed out..."));
      }, 5000);
    });

    const data4Server = { message: "CLIENT BELLO" };
    logger.info("Emitting BELLO event");
    socketClient.emit(ev.com_BELLO, data4Server);

    const { status, message } = await serverResponse;
    expect(status).toBe(200);
    expect(message).toBe("SERVER BELLO");
  });
});
```

**---- Foot Note ----**

Depending on how you setup your server environment, you may experience environmental conflict between socket.io and socket.io-client running from the same project simultaneously. In which case it would be better to separate the project into a "test client" and a server. Checkout below repo if you get this issue.

https://github.com/PatMan10/testing_socketIO_server_v2

Answer (score 3):

In OP's code,

```
socket.on('connect', function(done) {
    console.log('worked...');
    done();
});
```

the `done` was applied to the wrong callback. It should be removed from the `socket.on` callback and added to Mocha's `it` block callback:

```
it('First (hopefully useful) test', function (done) {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('worked...');
    done();
  });
});
```

---

### A complete example

Existing answers are great but don't show the server ultimately being tested. Here's a complete version with `console.log`s to illustrate what's going on. Explanation follows.

#### `src/server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");

const createServer = (port=3000) => {
  const app = express();
  const http = require("http").Server(app);
  const io = require("socket.io")(http);
  
  io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("[server] user connected");
    
    socket.on("message", msg => {
      console.log(`[server] received '${msg}'`);
      socket.emit("message", msg);
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("[server] user disconnected");
    });
  });
  
  http.listen(port, () =>
    console.log(`[server] listening on port ${port}`)
  );
  return {
    close: () => http.close(() => 
      console.log("[server] closed")
    )
  };
};
module.exports = {createServer};
```

#### `test/server.test.js`:

```
const {expect} = require("chai");
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const {createServer} = require("../src/server");
const socketUrl = "http://localhost:3000";

describe("server", function () {
  this.timeout(3000);
  
  let server;
  let sockets;
  beforeEach(() => {
    sockets = [];
    server = createServer();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sockets.forEach(e => e.disconnect())
    server.close();
  });
  
  const makeSocket = (id=0) => {
    const socket = io.connect(socketUrl, {
      "reconnection delay": 0,
      "reopen delay": 0,
      "force new connection": true,
      transports: ["websocket"],
    });
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log(`[client ${id}] connected`);
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(`[client ${id}] disconnected`);
    });
    sockets.push(socket);
    return socket;
  };
  
  it("should echo a message to a client", done => {
    const socket = makeSocket();
    socket.emit("message", "hello world");
    socket.on("message", msg => {
      console.log(`[client] received '${msg}'`);
      expect(msg).to.equal("hello world");
      done();
    });
  });
  
  it("should echo messages to multiple clients", () => {
    const sockets = [...Array(5)].map((_, i) => makeSocket(i));
    
    return Promise.all(sockets.map((socket, id) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const msgs = [..."abcd"].map(e => e + id);
        msgs.slice().forEach(e => socket.emit("message", e));
      
        socket.on("message", msg => {
          console.log(`[client ${id}] received '${msg}'`);
          expect(msg).to.equal(msgs.shift());
          
          if (msgs.length === 0) {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      })
    ));
  });
});
```

In summary, the server exports a function that lets a server app be created from scratch, allowing each `it` block to be idempotent and avoid server state from carrying between tests (assuming no persistence on the server otherwise). Creating an app returns an object with a `close` function. `socket.disconnect()` must be called per socket in each test to avoid timeouts.

Given these requirements, the testing suite follows this per-test setup/teardown workflow:

```
let server;
let sockets;
beforeEach(() => {
  sockets = [];
  server = createServer();
});
afterEach(() => {
  sockets.forEach(e => e.disconnect())
  server.close();
});
```

`makeSocket` is an optional helper to reduce the repeated boilerplate of connecting and disconnecting a socket client. It does produce a side effect on the `sockets` array for cleanup later, but this is an implementation detail from the `it` block's perspective. Test blocks shoudn't touch `server` or `sockets` variables, although other workflows are likely depending on need. The critical takeaways are test case idempotency and closing all connections after each test case.

Options on the `socket.connect` object on the client let you choose transport and behavior of the socket. `"force new connection": true` creates a new `Manager` per socket instead of reusing an existing one and `transports: ["websocket"]` upgrades to WS protocol from long polling immediately.

Use `it("should ... ", done => { /* tests */ });` and invoke `done()` after all work is completed in callbacks or return a promise (and omit the `done` parameter to the `it` callback). The example above shows both approaches.

---

Used in this post:

- `node`: 12.19.0
- `chai`: 4.2.0
- `express`: 4.16.4
- `mocha`: 5.2.0
- `socket.io`: 2.2.0
- `socket.io-client`: 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem: How to do unit test with a "socket.io-client" if you don't know how long the server take to respond?.

I've solved so using *mocha* and *chai*:

```
var os = require('os');
var should = require("chai").should();
var socketio_client = require('socket.io-client');

var end_point = 'http://' + os.hostname() + ':8081';
var opts = {forceNew: true};

describe("async test with socket.io", function () {
this.timeout(10000);

it('Response should be an object', function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var socket_client = socketio_client(end_point, opts);  

        socket_client.emit('event', 'ABCDEF');

        socket_client.on('event response', function (data) {
            data.should.be.an('object');
            socket_client.disconnect();
            done();
        });

        socket_client.on('event response error', function (data) {
            console.error(data);
            socket_client.disconnect();
            done();
            });
        }, 4000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The `{ forceNew: true }` is mighty important here :)