# Testing Web Sockets with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, websocket, jasmine, stomp

Here is some code that has been written for web-socket using stomp protocol.

```
function WS(url) {
    var ws = new SockJS('/notifications');

    this.client = Stomp.over(ws),

    this.client.connect('', '', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('STOMP protocol error: ', error.headers.message);
    });
}

WS.prototype.disconnect = function() {
};

WS.prototype.subscribe = function() {
};

WS.prototype.unSubscribe = function() {
};

WS.prototype.send = function(msg) {
};
```

I found this post but it requires actual connection to server,
[Unit testing Node.js and WebSockets (Socket.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509231/unit-testing-node-js-and-websockets-socket-io)

How do we test this using Jasmine. 
Looking for a way to fake web-socket server and fire events (connect, disconnect etc). I'll appreciate any example or useful link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just mock all your dependencies of your function, so in your case this will be `SockJS` and `Stomp.over`.

```
var wsSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
spyOn(window, 'SockJs').andReturn(wsSpy);

var clientSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
spyOne(Stomp, 'over').andReturn(clientSpy)
```

After running your script you can test on the spies that they was called. To run the callback functions you can use `mostRecentCall.args` to find them and call them in the test:

```
var successCallBack = clientSpy.mostRecentCall.args[2];
successCallBack();

var errorCallBack = clientSpy.mostRecentCall.args[3];
errorCallBack();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Getting this message 'Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to an unfinished async spec. Use --force to continue.'

Comment: excelent, I mock can mock WebSocket this way, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to Andreas accepted answer. The syntax for this has change in Jasmine as per http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-31

The new syntax as per Jasmine 2.3 would be:

```
clientSpy.calls.mostRecent().args
```