# Jest test WebSocket client API

Tags: node.js, websocket, jestjs

**Context :**

I have a WebSocket server program (.exe build with C#) and i want to test my request with a NodeJs client (in production mode, it will be NodeJs client app which going to use the "API") I use jest to test it

**My test code** :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

test('Extension Connection test', async ()=>{
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:2031/Extension");

    await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        ws.onmessage = function (message) {
            var responseAttended = {"type":"Information","data":{"information":"Success connection as Extension"},"target":"Extension"};
            assert(message.data, responseAttended);
            resolve();
        };

        ws.onopen = function () {
            var request = {target: "ExtensionService", type: "Auth", data: {name: "extension"}};
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(request));
        };

        ws.onerror = function () {
            assert(false);
            reject();
        }
    });
});
```

I started my server before launch test, my server catch the value send (so websocket is connected). My server did some stuff and send back the response, but it's looks like this one never arrived in my NodeJs test client

[image]

As no response arrived, the promise is not resolved and after 5s the jest timeout stop the test.

Any idea what i made bad ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could be of help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509231/unit-testing-node-js-and-websockets-socket-io

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `jest.setTimeout(millisecond)` before use `test()`, it work for me

```js
jest.setTimeout(10000);
test('Extension Connection test', async () => {
    // TODO your code
})
```